# sqlite: What's the difference between SQLiteTransaction and SQLiteTransaction2

Tags: .net, sqlite

System.Data.SQLite has two different classes for transactions: SQLiteTransaction and SQLiteTransaction2

Does anybody know the difference between SQLiteTransaction and SQLiteTransaction2?

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteTransaction2 supports nested transactions whilst SQLiteTransaction does not.

Look at the embedded class documentation:

```
//
// Summary:
//     SQLite implementation of DbTransaction that does support nested transactions.
public sealed class SQLiteTransaction2 : SQLiteTransaction
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Commits the current transaction.
    public override void Commit();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Attempts to start a transaction. An exception will be thrown if the transaction
    //     cannot be started for any reason.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   deferredLock:
    //     TRUE to defer the writelock, or FALSE to lock immediately
    protected override void Begin(bool deferredLock);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Disposes the transaction. If it is currently active, any changes are rolled back.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Issue a ROLLBACK command against the database connection, optionally re-throwing
    //     any caught exception.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   throwError:
    //     Non-zero to re-throw caught exceptions.
    protected override void IssueRollback(bool throwError);
}
```